# PowerBI issue with visuals colors matching application

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

MS Power BI - colors of visuals from JS API do not match the colors in the application.

I have tried applying a theme but when I provided it with the needed colors, it is always taking them from the top. I did not find a way to correlate colors with names/filters.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

As you can see in the images, black color is always applied to the first element.
The goal is, for example, to have "Cash & cash equivalents" always a black color — no matter what its position is.

Besides that, there is a gray box overlapping the visual. When I am forming a report, I add 3 visuals:
a title, chart, and border so this gray box is not one of them.

Any ideas on what can be done to make colors of visuals always match these in an application and where this gray box can come from?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the issue that you are facing.
Here are the steps I havefollowed:

1. Applying a theme to the embedded report in the react application. Went through the code snippet to apply theme. Referenced to [Power BI Playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/).
2. Modified the code accordingly and was able to apply a theme on the report.
   We did not find any kind of anomalies or difference in the report visuals after the report was embedded.
   Below are the snapshots for your reference.

**Report in Power BI Playground:**
[image]

**Report in the application:**
[image]